# I broke emacs auto-complete, How to re-enable it?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

New emacs user.
I have a simple init.el file created to learn emacs config.
I had auto-complete working such that while inside init.el file when I started to type (global, it would show the remaining on the word and would autocomplete.

A few key strokes later now it doesn't auto-complete anymore. According to google I have all right keywords in the init.el file. Spent nearly 3 hours and no luck.
 Any idea?

```
 2;; led packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
 3;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
 4;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
 5(package-initialize)
 6
 7(load-theme 'wombat)
 8(setq frame-title-format "emacs")
 9
10(menu-bar-mode -1)
11(tool-bar-mode -1)
12
13(scroll-bar-mode -1)
14(set-default 'cursor-type 'hbar)
15
16(column-number-mode)
17
18(show-paren-mode)
19
20(global-hl-line-mode)
21
22(winner-mode t)
23
24(windmove-default-keybindings)
25
26(require 'package)
27
28(add-to-list 'package-archives
29             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
30             t)
31
32(add-to-list 'package-archives
33             '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
34             t)
35
36(package-initialize)
37
38(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'smex)
39
40(ido-mode t)
41
42(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
43
44(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c M-x") 'execute-extended-command)
45
46(ac-config-default)
47
48(nlinum-mode)
49
50(autopair-global-mode)
51
52(global-undo-tree-mode)
53
54(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'undo-tree-visualize)
55
56(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-z") 'Switch-Window)
57
58(global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'ace-jump-mode)
59(require 'auto-complete)
60(global-auto-complete-mode t)
61
62(require 'evil)
63(evil-mode 1)
64(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-h") 'evil-window-left)
65(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
66(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
67(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-l") 'evil-window-right)
```

Comment: I see nothing in your init file that has anything to do with auto-completion.

Comment: I removed the evil mode and now auto-complete works again. But that is rather strange since it should not interfere with auto-complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that when I installing packages using package-install it was adding text to the init.el which was causing the issue. I removed the additional text, deleted the init.el content and retyped everything again. This time I did not use the package installer and it worked fine.